# Mac Lion and getting rid of commands I have entered via terminal

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I entered a command in terminal and had Mac OS lion execute it successfully.  I simply would like to stop that execution and negate what I had the computer do.  I have done the history -c 
command and the terminal history is gone but the command execution is still happening.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is the standard "interrupt" key on – all Unix-like systems, including OS X.

However, there is no standard "undo this". Once you ran a command to do something, and it did something, it is done. How to undo it – or whether it's at all possible to undo it – depends very much on *what exact command you ran*.

Answer (score 0):

You likely 'backgrounded' the processes,

Type `jobs` to see any background processes

Type `fg` to resume the #1 background process

Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to interrupt the process.

If all else fails, run `ps aux`, find the process id and send it a kill 9, or just run `top`

---

Side note: top is kind of ugly, install htop